# How can I know if user has switched to other application from current browser?

Tags: javascript

We can know if user has switched from current tab to another by using document.hidden.
When user switches between app document.hidden remains false.

But how can we check if user has switched to another app from current browser ?

Example: Am on my test-page, it has some javascript, it should set some flag on some event when I switch from my browser to say Skype or any other app. I do not require info about other app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active